# user_id may not be NULL in django

Tags: python

i have two model User and Customer I have customer   = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='orders') in Customer model, I want both User and Customer form to be saved together and if there is error in one form then both shouldnt be saved. When i created a view to save both it has given me error that mainsiteapp_customer.user_id may not be NULL.

i have tried every possible way my final code is as below
def userForm(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    userform = UserForm(request.POST)
    customerform = CustomerForm(request.POST)          
    if userform.is_valid():
    u = userform.save()

        Customer.user = u
        print Customer.user
        if customerform.is_valid():
           c = customerform.save(commit=False)    

           try:
               c.full_clean()
               c.save()
               print c
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/webshop/')
           except ValidationError, e:
               pass
        u.delete()

else:

    userform = UserForm()
    customerform = CustomerForm()
context = RequestContext(request, {'userform':userform, 'customerform':customerform,})
return render_to_response('userRegister.html', context)
```

its now 9 days i couldnt find where m i doing wrong.

if someone know where m i doing wrong
thanks

Comment: "I have customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='orders') in Customer model" Are you trying to self join? or did you mean that is in the User model? Can you post your Customer and User models. The error you are getting indicates that you have a user_id fk in your customer model that isn't being set

Answer (score 1):

```
Customer.user = u
if customerform.is_valid():
    c = customerform.save(commit=False)
```

You're setting the model's class variable `user` here. Instead you want to set the customer's user property like `c.user = u`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if both userform and customerform are valid using an and statement

```
def userForm(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        userform = UserForm(request.POST)
        customerform = CustomerForm(request.POST)          
        if userform.is_valid() and customerform.is_valid():
            c = customerform.save()   
            u = userform.save(commit=False)
            u.customer=c
            u.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/webshop/')
    else:
        userform = UserForm()
        customerform = CustomerForm()
    context = RequestContext(request, {'userform':userform, 'customerform':customerform,})
    return render_to_response('userRegister.html', context)
```